# issues in the implementation background_locator_2 with firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to implement background_locator 2 with firebase but when I want to save data in my firebase I get that firebase has not been initialized. I found this publication with the problem in more detail but in this post it gives the solution with an old version by backgroun_locator, this is my implementation

```kotlin
override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
    if (!registry.hasPlugin("io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin")) {
        PathProviderPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin"))
    }
    if (!registry.hasPlugin("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin")) {
        FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin"))
    }
    if (!registry.hasPlugin("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin")) {
        FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin"))
    }
    if (!registry.hasPlugin("yukams.app.background_locator_2.BackgroundLocatorPlugin")) {
        BackgroundLocatorPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("yukams.app.background_locator_2.BackgroundLocatorPlugin"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are initializing Firebase before using it

```
if (!registry.hasPlugin("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin")) {
FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin"))
```

}

and in the `void main()`

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

This will initilize the firebase.

Comment: I already have it like this but it doesn't work, this is the error in the console e: D:\B\PROYECTO\PROYECTO\android\app\src\main\kotlin\Application.kt: (24, 39): Unresolved reference: registerWith
e: D:\B\PROYECTO\PROYECTO\android\app\src\main\kotlin\Application.kt: (27, 44): Unresolved reference: registerWith
e: D:\B\PROYECTO\PROYECTO\android\app\src\main\kotlin\Application.kt: (30, 37): Unresolved reference: registerWith

Comment: This issue seems to be with Kotlin, without checking the code, I can't help you. However, the original problem that you shared is solved.

Comment: Read more here

https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=blocprovider